# Why is my .NET web service XML different to somebody else's?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, soap

Im new to .NET web services and am thoroughly confused with this issue. TCP Viewer shows that my test app talking to my web service forms its XML as follows:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetSupply xmlns="http://webservices.florecom.org/commercial/customer/">
      <Request>
        <SupplyRequest>
          <Header xmlns="urn:fec:florecom:xml:data:draft:SupplyStandardMessage:5">
            <UserName>xxx</UserName>
            <Password>xxx</Password>
            <MessageDateTime>2012-01-17T14:59:44.0438037+02:00</MessageDateTime>
            <MessageSerial>0</MessageSerial>
          </Header>
          <Body xmlns="urn:fec:florecom:xml:data:draft:SupplyStandardMessage:5">
            <SupplyRequestDetails>
              <SupplyRequestLine xmlns="urn:fec:florecom:xml:data:draft:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:3"/>
            </SupplyRequestDetails>
          </Body>
        </SupplyRequest>
      </Request>
    </GetSupply>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But my web service is receiving XML from another company that looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <fsm:SupplyRequest xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:QualifiedDataType:5" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:4" xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:draft:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:3" xmlns:fsm="urn:fec:florecom:xml:data:draft:SupplyStandardMessage:5">
      <fsm:Header>
        <fsm:UserName>xxx</fsm:UserName>
        <fsm:Password>xxx</fsm:Password>
        <fsm:MessageID>634617184436505019</fsm:MessageID>
        <fsm:MessageDateTime>2012-01-09T15:07:23.6505019+01:00</fsm:MessageDateTime>
        <fsm:MessageSerial>0</fsm:MessageSerial>
      </fsm:Header>
      <fsm:Body>
        <fsm:SupplyRequestDetails>
          <SupplyRequestLine xmlns="urn:fec:florecom:xml:data:draft:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:3"/>
        </fsm:SupplyRequestDetails>
      </fsm:Body>
    </fsm:SupplyRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can someone help explain why? Are these different versions of SOAP? Thanks

**UPDATE**

As a matter of interest, the problem that is occurring in this scenario (with the 2nd XML message) is that when the service method gets hit (used a breakpoint to check this and spoofed the message with Fiddler) .NET fails to bind the method's parameter (called 'Request') so its value remains NULL

Comment: They look the same to me, and if they weren't you would get errors

Comment: @Jontatas: Unfortunately, I am getting errors (see Update above) and the messages are (in my n00b eyes) quite different?

Comment: I'd say you stumbled upon the same thing I noticed while consuming data from a webservice in our integration platform. The funny thing is if I return one object it works, but for array data it's a no go. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485744

Comment: That's the most complex way to pass strings between servers, ever.  You might consider using REST instead, and eliminated all the namespace, header, body and envelope junk, and problems you're having with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to the soap vs s its actually not really important. those nodes are the namespaces so that the consumer knows the format of the document. They will actually be processed identically by someone who knows the schema defined by http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope

Both refer to the soap 1.1 namespace

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesnt explain why although it hits the service method, the supplied parameter is still Null in the 2nd message, but works in the 1st message.

Comment: In the service method called `GetSupply`, the parameter is called `Request` - it binds in the 1st message, but not the second

Comment: your second message is missing 2 XML nodes, <GetSupply> and <Request> This means the second request is not correctly constructed for your webservice. You can deal with this in two possible ways, 1. get the caller to fix the request they are making to include those two wrapper nodes in their request, or 2. change your webservice so that it no longer needs those two nodes (which may be a bit fiddly).